# Sencha Touch 2 Application Doesn't Work on Android Phones, but Works on Virtual Android Devices

Tags: android, mobile, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a mobile web application (not packaged through PhoneGap) that is successfully working on Chrome, Safari, and Safari mobile on iOS, but I have not had any success on Android Phones or with Firefox.

However, when I run the app on a virtual Android device (2.3 or higher) it works fine. What can I do to make sure that it works on both?

On the HTC Hero (Android 2.1), it doesn't seem like it makes it into the initialization of the first view. As for other devices (higher than 2.3) I just get a blank screen.

Let me know about any other information that I can provide. I can test on virtual devices lower or higher than 2.3 and report those errors, provide code samples, etc.

All help is appreciated. We feel that our app is so close to launch, this is all that is holding us back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, It won't work on Firefox. Firefox don't possess a `web-kit-engine` which Sencha Touch requires.

> but I have not had any success on Android Phones

You can start your localhost using some s/w like `WampServer`, `Apache Web Server`, put all of your code inside the root directory and try accessing it on your android phone via URL like

```
http://_your_ip_address:_portno_/_root_directory_/app/
```

Comment: The web kit item was the issue! That and the fact that Sencha doesn't support Android versions lower than 2.3

Comment: Actually 2.2 is also supported. 2.1 will work, though has no optimization done for it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all paths(to javascript files,css...) relative? Maybe you can try it also with phonegap. It's not a lot of effort and it can help at least figure out where is problem.

Also you can try to access app in your computer/localhost or some other host from android phone browser and you will see if it loads.

Comment: Turns out it was a browser support issue.  Thanks for the help!